# LocalDate: missing methods isEqualOrBefore and isEqualOrAfter

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

*Question*: How are you handling these use cases?

- do you use static helper methods?
- do you use the verbose equals followed by isAfter/isBefore?
- do you use the negated opposite condition?
- do you use 3rd party library helpers?

In daily business, I often need to check if date a <= date b or if date a >= date b.

The internet often suggests to use the negated versions of isBefore/isAfter methods.

In practice I find that I

- almost never get these negated comparisons right on the first try (and they should be intuitive and easy).
- have a hard time understanding the business logic when reading the code

I guess part of me is still hoping that I just overlooked the corresponding methods in the API (please!).

```
  /**
   * @return true if candidate >= reference </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>candidate.equals(reference) || candidate.isAfter(reference)</code> </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>!candidate.isBefore(reference) </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>candidate.compareTo(reference) >= 0
   */
  public static boolean isEqualOrAfter(LocalDate candidate, LocalDate reference)
  {
    return !candidate.isBefore(reference);
  }

  /**
   * @return true if candidate <= reference </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>candidate.equals(reference) || candidate.isBefore(reference)</code> </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>!candidate.isAfter(reference) </br>
   *         or in other words: <code>candidate.compareTo(reference) <= 0
   */
  public static boolean isEqualOrBefore(LocalDate candidate, LocalDate reference)
  {   
    return !candidate.isAfter(reference);
  }
```

EDIT: As suggested by Andreas, I added the version with `compareTo` method, I hope I got them right (without testing).

EDIT 2: Example:

```
// Manager says: "Show me everything from 3 days ago or later" or "show me everything that's at most 3 days old"
for(Item item : items) {
  // negation idiom
  if(!item.getDate().isBefore(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3))) {
    // show
  }

  // compareTo idiom
  if(item.getDate().compareTo(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3)) >= 0) {
    // show
  }

  // desired
  if(item.getDate().isEqualOrAfter(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3))) {
    // show
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the equals method, before and after are sufficient. To test equality use equals().

Comment: @StimpsonCat technically you are right of course, but the whole point of this question is to complain that it is not convenient at all (and very error prone for me and many others)

Comment: Voted to close as "primarily opinion-based", since the answer to *"How are you handling these use cases?"* is entirely opinion-based. --- But, you forgot to list `compareTo()`. Note that `a.isAfter(b)`, `a.isBefore(b)`, and `a.isEqual(b)` is exactly the same as `a.compareTo(b) > 0`, `a.compareTo(b) < 0`, and `a.compareTo(b) == 0`, respectively, so your `a.isEqualOrAfter(b)` and `a.isEqualOrBefore(b)` is the same as `a.compareTo(b) >= 0` and `a.compareTo(b) <= 0`.

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right of course, and I knew you would close it for this reason. It's just that the pain was strong enough. And another part of me hopes that this question might cause java 9 or 10 to include these convenience methods. And yes, I forgot compareTo. My SQL code looks like that (DATEDIFF). I also do not find it very intuitive and error prone.

Comment: If you want Java 9 or 10 to include these methods, you should file an enhancement request, but post a question here. --- And you do not find **compareTo() <= 0** to be intuitive?? It is a simply transformation of **a *op* b** to **a.compareTo(b) *op* 0**, where ***op*** can be `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`, e.g. `a <= b` is written as `a.compareTo(b) <= 0`. It is very common when using `BigDecimal`, and now also when using the new `java.time` classes.

Comment: @Andreas Again you are right, what can I say. And no, I don't find compareTo intuitive at all. I have exactly the same problem there: I never get them right initially and I find them hard to read. I would prefer to write the code in language very close to the business requirement.

Comment: @Andreas: a few days ago, I had said “no chance to get something into Java 9, so short before the intended release date”, but now, all bets are off…

Comment: for your example, I would prefer: `LocalDate itemDate = item.getDate(); LocalDate threeDaysAgo = LocalDate.now().minus(3); ..... if (itemDate.compareTo(threeDaysAgo) >= 0) {... }`.  `compareTo` convention is actually not difficult to read.  You may add a comment to show what it means (`// itemDate >= 3-days-ago` ) .  Honestly I don't think a util method of `XxxUtil.afterOrEqual(yDate, bDate)` is anything better than `compareTo`.  Your eyes needs to move a bit forward and backward to understand the statement in both cases

Comment: On the business logic side of things, comments should take care of most of it.

Answer (score 4):

The methods you seek are unnecesary. That's how you do it:

```
isEqualOrBefore == !isAfter
isEqualOrAfter == !isBefore
```

Comment: See this is exactly where I strongly disagree (and the reason why Andreas flags this question as primarily opinion based). I find this proposed solution inconvenient, not very readable and very error-prone (in my experience).

Comment: Also I would argue that the fact that I seek these methods makes them necessary.

Comment: There is no question of necessity, they are not necessary. You may think them convenient and readable, but I disagree with you. What I proposed is "error prone" only to a careless or newbie programmer who fails to notice the all-important `!`. And the mistake to not-notice this would be made exactly once. As for your suggestion, I don't like it. Long method names like `isEqualOrBefore` are much less readable, mostly because they consist of many words and one can not see them wholly at first glance. Secondly, if I had to, I'd name it isBeforeOrEqual, to distinguish the 2 better.

Comment: That would also fit the `<=` operator, i.e. `<` or `=`, aka before-or-equal. --- In fact, one could argue that `isBefore`, `isEqual`, and `isAfter` are all superfluous *(opinion)*, since all six comparison operators can be done using `a.compareTo(b) OP 0`, where `OP` is `<`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, or `<=`. See [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932309/localdate-missing-methods-isequalorbefore-and-isequalorafter/43932750?noredirect=1#comment74898134_43932750).

Comment: @Dariusz I would be very happy with `isBeforeOrEqual`, and I agree that it would be more consistent with the operator syntax. In fact I am going to rename my helper methods. Edit: On second thought maybe not. Business language is often "on that day or later".

Comment: @Andreas It would fit the operator `<=`. There is a big difference though between a two-character operator `<=` and `isBeforeOrEqual` conveniance method. The first one is easily readable at first glance, the other is not. I agree the compareTo point could be argued, but Java's compareTo is not as readable, mostly because it returns an int (if it returned an enum {LESS,EQUAL,GREATER}) I'd use it all the time.

Comment: I've used `compareTo` a lot with `BigDecimal`, and have never had a problem reading `a.compareTo(b) <= 0` as `a <= b`. The important parts are `a`, `b`, and `<=`. The `compareTo` and `0` are just minor filler code, easy to read past. It's a standard construct you'll quickly learn to recognize. It's not like you really need to translate it to understand the meaning. `<=` means `<=`.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't either, but I prefer `isAfter` or `isBefore` to it because of that magic number `0` (and -1, 1). When you think about it, these are instances of magic number anti-pattern.

Comment: @Dariusz The problem is that there are no magic numbers `-1` and `1`. It seems a lot of people think so, but `compareTo()` returns `< 0`, `== 0`, or `> 0`. By contract, it does not return `-1` or `1`, though many implementations happen to do so, but you should **never** rely on that, because it is an *implementation* detail, not a requirement, and may change in the future. There is only one magic number, `0`, and I don't see that as much of an anti-pattern, for a method returning a *sign* indicator *(opinion)*.

Comment: I always assumed it did, never used it though. `== -1` is much less readable than `< 0`. Nice to know anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Is compareTo consistent for these types (Well they implement Comparable)?
I remember the inline documentation suggesting the "idiom":

```
(a.compareTo(b) <operator> 0), so

for isEqualOrBefore: (a.compareTo(b) <= 0)
for isEqualOrAfter:  (a.compareTo(b) >= 0)
```

Comment: Yes I think they are, as Andreas already pointed out. I included these options in my question code. However, in addition to the readability problems, just the fact that you have to ask yourself if the method is consistent makes that approach inferior to isEqualOrAfter, in my opinion.

Comment: Ah OK, didn't see update until after posting. I often got compareTo wrong -
 until I read that line in the class file!

Comment: It is a common idiom from `BigDecimal`, since Java 1.0. See javadoc of [`BigDecimal.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-): *This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `<=`). The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: `(x.compareTo(y)` <op> `0)`, where <op> is one of the six comparison operators.*

Comment: @Andreas yes, `BigDecimal` would benefit from additional convenience methods for these comparisons as well.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you - I was wondering why I couldn't find it again it under Comparable - whether the comment was from an older version. I think it would be useful if they copied it to Comparable too.